# Linux console resolution too high

Tags: linux, resolution, console

I am using Debian squeeze (2.6.32-5-amd64) on a single board computer powered by as Intel Atom CPU D425 the graphic controller is detected as "VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation N10 Family" which is correct.

I need it to work with an small flat screen 9' with a max resolution of 640x480.

Bios splash screen and Grub menu display well. Very soon after the kernel is selected, the console goes in a video mode incompatible with the screen. (the last readable line is : Waiting for /dev to be fully populated.)

With a larger screen every thing is fine.

I have tried the good old deprecated way (you never know) to add vga=769 to boot arguments. but it really is deprecated and didn't work.

I have triyed various things : setting GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=" gfxpayload=true gfxpayload=640x480x8" in /etc/default/grub but it didn't change a thing.

I changed /etc/grub.d/00_header to add "set gfxpayload=keep" with no luck.

And now I don't know what to do... Any help would be verry apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Boot your kernel with vga=ask and select an appropriate resolution. Find whatever fits your small notebook and set in the grub file as you described in your question.

Comment: This only work for initial resolution.